# How to get board game pawns position

Tags: hardware, bluetooth, nfc

I am building a semi-digital version of the famous Monopoly game.
For this, I'm using a screen with a Bubble.io app for the interface:

[image: Board game]

Now, I would ideally like to detect the physical position of the pawn on the board game to avoid the player's frustration (they won't have to log their position manually every time they roll the dice)

For that, I've thought of a few things:

- Use an iBeacon-like system to get their position from the edges of the board, but the math and implementation seem complex
- Have an NFC/RFID reader on top of every board cell, but this seems expensive (28 cells)
- Have a huge NFC/RFID reader on top of the entire board, and be able to detect their position based on voltage input or something, but also seem very complex.

Knowing that the board is actually a screen, so ideally it would be either a transparent surface (yeah  :D or invisible such as iBeacon) or a flat surface in the middle of the board.
Also, this is obviously a leisure project, so the cheaper the better!

I would love to get some input from more experienced users because I don't really know which direction to take  :?

Love!
Victor

Comment: I don't think iBeacon would give you the positional accuracy that you would need for such a game. https://www.instructables.com/Object-Interaction-With-Touchscreens/ shows doing something that might be useful with touchscreens.

Comment: Interesting, but off-topic as the Pi is irrelevant to any answer.

Comment: @ukBaz Thanks! This is really really interesting and doesn't seem overcomplicated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you "paint" the location of the various pawns on the squares & move it based on the "dice roll"?